# Reduction operator does not work properly

Tags: verilog, counter, system-verilog, hdl, fsm

I have a FSM design that uses a counter to count up inside a particular state and stay there until the expression `&counter`yields `TRUE`, however when it finishes (gets 1111...111 - checking via simulator) `&counter` never goes `HIGH` and stucks on that state like an infinite loop. How to overcome this issue? I will provide my buggy part of the code. I'm quite new in verilog so hopefully it is an easy-to-catch problem.

```
reg [2:0] State, NextState;
reg [20:0] counter;
reg EN;

//State register 
always @(posedge Clk) begin 
    if(Rst) begin
        counter <= 0;
        State <= S0;
    end
    else begin
        State <= NextState;
        counter <= EN ? counter + 1 : 0;
    end
end

//Next State Logic
always @(State, COL)
    case(State)
        S0: begin 
            NextState <= S1;
            EN <= 0;
        end
        S1: begin 
            if(ROW) begin
                if(COL) begin 
                    if(&counter[18:0]) begin // <--- THIS EXP. NEVER GETS 1
                        PrevCOL <= COL;
                        NextState <= S3;
                        EN <= 0;
                    end
                    else begin
                        EN <= 1;
                        NextState <= S1;
                    end
                end
                else
                    NextState <= S2;
            end
            else
                NextState <= S0;
        end
        S2:  NextState <= S1;
        S3: begin
            if(PrevCOL == COL) begin
                if(&counter) begin // <-------- THIS EXPRESSION NEVER GETS 1
                    NextState <= S4;
                    EN <= 0;
                    case(ROW)
                        8: 
                            case(COL)
                                8: ID <= I0;
                                4: ID <= I1;
                                2: ID <= I2;
                                1: ID <= I3;
                            endcase
                        4:
                            case(COL)
                                8: ID <= I4;
                                4: ID <= I5;
                                2: ID <= I6;
                                1: ID <= I7;
                            endcase
                        2:
                            case(COL)
                                8: ID <= I8;
                                4: ID <= I9;
                                2: ID <= I10;
                                1: ID <= I11;
                            endcase
                        1:
                            case(COL)
                                8: ID <= I12;
                                4: ID <= I13;
                                2: ID <= I14;
                                1: ID <= I15;
                            endcase
                    endcase
                end
                else begin
                    NextState <= S3;
                    EN <= 1;
                end
            end
            else
                NextState <= S0;
        end
        S4: NextState <= S0;
    endcase
```

Buggy area is indicated with the comment. Why its not working?

Thank you!

Comment: Why you are using `&counter[18:0]` and not `counter[18:0]` since `counter` is just a register variable?

Comment: Okay, got it. You want all 19 bits of `counter` to be `1`. Looks like as soon as `EN` is made low, `counter` gets reset. Also, you are driving `EN` while transitioning from `S0` to `S1` which instantly resets `counter` on the next clock pulse. This may be the cause but I am not sure about it unless some testbench is provided. :)

Comment: @sharvil111 First of all thank you for your efforts! :) I'm quite newbie in this field but constantly trying to learn new stufff! :) And yes the answer below actually solved my problem. I found out that self-loop actually does not initiate that always procedure which was looking for any change in State or COL. Therefore by including @(*) it began to work well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For combinatorial logic, avoid writing sensitivity list by yourself. You should substitute this:

```
always @(State, COL)
```

With

```
always @(*)
```

You can also use always_comb. Basically, your second always block does not execute when counter is incrementing. It only executes when State or COL signals change.

Secondly you should not use nonblocking assignment (<=) in combinatorial logic. Substitute all of them in your second "always" block with blocking assignments(=).

Comment: but sir, for combinational logic, shouldn't it need to be different from sequential logic? which has nothing to do with clock? If I were to put @(*), it will include the clock either.

Comment: **No**, unless the clock is on RHS of any assignment. Refer to LRM 1800-2012 section 9.2. `always @(*) y = (a & b) | (c & d) | myfunction(f);` is equivalent to `always @(a or b or c or d or f)`. `always @(*)` is sensitive to all the variables on the **RHS** of the assignment. Similar applies to `always_comb` but with some twists and differences.

Comment: FYI: There is an additional issue with the code. `EN`, `PrevCOL`, and `ID` are inferred complex latches.

Comment: @sharvil111 By the way, what if we didn't have anything on the RHS but constants? What would be in the sensitivity list if I were to write `@(*)`? Nothing I guess, could result in infinite loop.

Comment: @Greg What is the possible disadvantages of being complex latches? I'd really appreciate If you can provide some link related to this issue

Comment: @Burak if your RHS is having only constants, then why use always block at all. You can provide default values to regs, `assign` statements can also be used for driving constant value continuously. `always_comb` is also available for guaranteed zero time execution. I guess you are misinterpreting/confused in the usage of  `*`. Greg's answer is a good example here.

Answer (score 2):

As Convergent has pointed out. `always @(State, COL)` should be `always @*` (synonymous with `always @(*)`) or SystemVerilog's `always_comb`, and blocking assignments (`=`) should be used in combinational blocks; not non-blocking (`<=`).

The additional problem is are the inferred complex latches in `EN`, `PrevCOL`, and `ID`. When I say latch, I mean level sensitive (active high/low) latch. When I say flop, I'm referring to edge triggered flip-flops.

An inferred latch is when when a `reg` is not assigned a value for all possible paths within the always block. On its own, a latch is not a bad thing so long it was intended, data respects setup and hold time, and the enable pin is glitch free. Often, are not necessary and considered a design bug by many. FPGAs usually have far more flops and logic gates then latches (latches make form intend logic gates get worse timing then dedicated latches). If a latch is used, it is best to keep it as simple as possible, put it in an always block separate from decoding logic, and use non-blocking assignment. Verilog has only implicate latches; lint and LEC(logical-equivalent-checks) will throw warnings for possible design bugs. SystemVerilog allows explicit latches; link and LEC will not throw warnings. Examples below. In summary, use latches only when needed and keep them simple.

```
// Verilog clean implicit latch
always @* begin
  if (lat_en)    // requirement: 'lat_en' must be glitch free
    lat <= data; // requirement: 'data' must respects setup/hold time
end
// SystemVerilog explicit latch
always_latch begin
  if (lat_en)    // requirement: 'lat_en' must be glitch free
    lat <= data; // requirement: 'data' must respects setup/hold time
end
```

An inferred **complex** latch is more dangerous than simple a latch. A complex latch's enable pin or data is based on other combinational logic or latches. It is very hard to meet timing and often glitch. This means your code could run fine for a while, then unexpectedly get the wrong data. They are nasty to debug as timing window the glitch can occur on changes when synthesized and SDF annotation is applied, and can change again FPGA or silicon based on other variables. A glitch could even happen in RLT simulation in 0-time depending on event scheduling. Again in summary, use latches only when needed and keep them simple.

When it comes to RTL coding style, I typically follow Cliff Cummings' recommendations of a 2-always block solution (one for next state combinational logic, the other for synchronous assignments):

- [The Fundamentals of Efficient Synthesizable Finite State Machine
  Design](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsICU2002_FSMFundamentals.pdf)
- [Coding And Scripting Techniques For FSM Designs With
  Synthesis-Optimized, Glitch-Free Outputs](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000Boston_FSM.pdf)

There are additional links to useful Verilog/SystemVerilog references in my profile.

I recommend making `EN`, `PrevCOL`, and `ID` into proper flops with there respected `next_*` assigned calculated in a combinational block.

```
//Synchronous Logic Assignments
always @(posedge Clk) begin // SV: use 'always_ff' instead of 'always'
  if(Rst) begin
    counter <= 0;
    State <= S0;
    EN <= 0;
    PrevCOL <= 0;
    ID <= 0;
  end
  else begin
    State <= NextState;
    counter <= next_EN ? counter + 1 : 0;
    EN <= next_EN;
    PrevCOL <= next_PrefCOL;
    ID <= next_ID;
  end
end

//Next State Logic Calculations
always @* begin // SV: use 'always_comb' instead of 'always @*'
  // Default value assignments
  next_EN = EN;
  next_PrevCOL = PrevCOL;
  next_ID = ID;

  // Update value logic
  case(State)
    // Update NextState and next_* values in here
  endcase
end
```

---

FYI for `always @*` where RHS is only constants, then may not ever execute in simulation. This condition is not defined of the LRM, some creator of the simulator decided to implement time 0 execution, others didn't. It will synthesize correctly. SystemVerilog's `always_comb` is better because it will execute at time 0. See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 9.2.2.2.2 *`always_comb` compared to `always @*`*. With Verilog you can use `assign` statements.